# What is the minimum setup for this Troll adept Grenade-thrower character?

Tags: weapons, optimization, throwing-things, shadowrun-sr3

Back in the late-90 Shadowrun 3 days, someone made a character that he told about repeatedly in the local game store <sup>1</sup>. It was a Troll adept that would throw grenades. Instead of using the grenades for their explosive value, he'd throw them without pulling the pin to *plunge holes into people*.

He never revealed the full build of this Troll-thrower and it supposedly had been years since he played that character when he told about it, so the above is pretty much all I know. However, I believe it must have been a quite focus-designed build. For simplicity's sake, let's assume a grenade with its pin not pulled has the same damage as a rock, and our Troll adept doesn't need to provide for anything but this target with his priorities.

**What is the minimum setup for a Troll adept to inflict equal damage to a single target with a rock as with an exploding grenade right at the person's feet?**

---

1. <sub>until that stopped due to the 2020 coronavirus restrictions. I haven't seen them since and have no contact info.</sub>